# How to reduce 2 image bands simultaneously using grouped sum region reducer in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, reducers

I am trying to reduce a region to simultaneously obtain forest loss and forest cover by year from the Hansen dataset. I have tried doing this using a grouped reducer, however, I get the following error: 
  "Dictionary (Error)
ReduceRegion.AggregationContainer: Need 2 bands for Reducer.group(Reducer.sum), <Image<[forest_area, forest_loss, lossyear]>> has 3."
Is there an inherent reason why this is not possible or am I doing something wrong? From one of the GEE tutorials, it seemed like it should be possible to do this but I have found no examples.

This is the immediate code I am using with the first 3 variables being modified bands from the original dataset.

```
var protectedLoss = dataset.select(['loss']).clip(protectedAreas);  
var protectedLossYear = dataset.select(['lossyear']).clip(protectedAreas);  
var protectedForestLoss = blank.where(treeCover.gt(forestDef).and(protectedLoss.eq(1)),1).clip(protectedAreas);
var protectedChart = protectedDataset.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
groupField: 2}), geometry: protectedAreas,  scale: 30,  maxPixels: 1e12`
```

Apologies if this is a basic question - I am new to GEE.